# OTP validation check in node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodemailer

I created an web application where there is no data base it is an simple application. If user want to login to this website user need to verify through his mailID, When user entered mailid an 4 digit OTP will be sent to user mail. After that he need to verify with that to login.

Prob: I am unable to call endpoint to send email I am getting 404 error.

error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.

This is login.html file:

```
<body>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="container">
                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    
                <button type="button" id="otp-btn">Get OTP</button>
            </div>
    
            <div class="container">
                <label for="otp"><b>OTP</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter OTP" name="otp" required>
                <button id="loginBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Login</button>

                
            </div>
        </form>
    
        <script>
            const otpBtn = document.getElementById('otp-btn');
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn');

// Disable the login button by default
loginBtn.disabled = true;

// Add event listener for "Get OTP" button
otpBtn.addEventListener('click', async function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting normally

  // Send request to server to send OTP
  const email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
  const response = await fetch('/generateOTP', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email })
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  // Update UI based on response
  if (data.success) {
    alert('OTP sent to your email!');
    loginBtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    alert('Failed to send OTP. Please try again later.');
  }
});

// Add event listener for form submission
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting normally

  // Send request to server to validate OTP
  const email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
  const otp = document.querySelector('input[name="otp"]').value;
  const response = await fetch('/verify-otp', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, otp })
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  // Update UI based on response
  if (data.success) {
    alert('OTP validation successful!');
    window.location.href = '/MF.html';
  } else {
    alert('Invalid OTP. Please try again.');
  }
});
        </script>
</body>
```

This is server.js file :

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'login.html'));
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
      user: "my@gmail.com",
      pass: "password"
  }
});

const otp = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);







app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { otp } = req.body;
  // Verify the OTP code
  // In this example, we are using a hardcoded value for demonstration purposes only.
  // In a real application, you should compare the OTP to the one generated in the previous step.
  
  if (otp === this.otpCode && otp!=0) {
    print("otp");
    print("otp"+otp);
    print(this.otpCode+"this otp");
    console.log(otp);
    console.log(this.otpCode);
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Login successful' });
    
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid OTP' });
  }
});

app.post("/generateOTP", (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;

  // Generate a new OTP code and send it via email
  this.otpCode = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
  const mailOptions = {
    from: "my@gmail.com",
    to: email,
    subject: "LogIn OTP",
    text: `Your OTP code is ${this.otpCode}.`,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, _info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email: ', error);
      res.status(500).send({ message: 'Failed to send OTP' });
    } else {
      console.log('OTP sent: ', this.otpCode);
      res.status(200).send({ message: 'OTP sent successfully' });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you are sending the form data to **'/verify-otp'** endpoint, so does that exist?

Comment: Yes I created that in server.js file I gave code above

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `/verify-otp` endpoint on your server.
**EDIT**
So based on your code, on client side you are calling the `/verify-otp` endpoint to perform otp verification. However on your server.js, that endpoint doesn't exist. However i have noticed that you are performing otp verification in your '/login' endpoint on your server.js. So changing `app.post("/login")` to `app.post("/verify-otp")` should fix.

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
      user: "my@gmail.com",
      pass: "password"
  }
});

const otp = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);







app.post("/verify-otp", (req, res) => {
  const { otp } = req.body;
  // Verify the OTP code
  // In this example, we are using a hardcoded value for demonstration purposes only.
  // In a real application, you should compare the OTP to the one generated in the previous step.
  
  if (otp === this.otpCode && otp!=0) {
    print("otp");
    print("otp"+otp);
    print(this.otpCode+"this otp");
    console.log(otp);
    console.log(this.otpCode);
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Login successful' });
    
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid OTP' });
  }
});

app.post("/generateOTP", (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;

  // Generate a new OTP code and send it via email
  this.otpCode = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
  const mailOptions = {
    from: "my@gmail.com",
    to: email,
    subject: "LogIn OTP",
    text: `Your OTP code is ${this.otpCode}.`,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, _info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email: ', error);
      res.status(500).send({ message: 'Failed to send OTP' });
    } else {
      console.log('OTP sent: ', this.otpCode);
      res.status(200).send({ message: 'OTP sent successfully' });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Abcd</title>
    </head>
<body>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="container">
                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    
                <button type="button" id="otp-btn">Get OTP</button>
            </div>
    
            <div class="container">
                <label for="otp"><b>OTP</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter OTP" name="otp" required>
                <button id="loginBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Login</button>

                
            </div>
        </form>
    
        <script>
            const otpBtn = document.getElementById('otp-btn');
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn');

// Disable the login button by default
loginBtn.disabled = true;

// Add event listener for "Get OTP" button
otpBtn.addEventListener('click', async function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting normally

  // Send request to server to send OTP
  const email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
  const response = await fetch('/generateOTP', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email })
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  // Update UI based on response
  if (data.success) {
    alert('OTP sent to your email!');
    loginBtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    alert('Failed to send OTP. Please try again later.');
  }
});

// Add event listener for form submission
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting normally

  // Send request to server to validate OTP
  const email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
  const otp = document.querySelector('input[name="otp"]').value;
  const response = await fetch('/verify-otp', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, otp })
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  // Update UI based on response
  if (data.success) {
    alert('OTP validation successful!');
    window.location.href = '/MF.html';
  } else {
    alert('Invalid OTP. Please try again.');
  }
});
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its already there

Comment: server means where like server.js file ?? I provided that file code above . Can you please check once. I have only these two files of code, Is there anything do I need to add ? Any suggestions

Comment: Oh my bad i didn’t seen the full code on a phone, well with the current code it seems like it’s the /verify-otp endpoint that is missing. Yes in the server.js

Comment: I am getting an error like : login:140          POST http://localhost:3000/generateOTP 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ login:140
VM164:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Comment: On server.js try changing port from 5000 to 3000

Comment: I already tried no luck. I am really stuck here can you please share your mail id, so we can connect very quick and resolve this ?

Comment: I just tried on my machine and it is working though, you must be missing something, i edited my answer with the code i tried.